# Page Redirect for Mobile View on Submit

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, so I am pretty sure there has to be a simple solution to my issue, I'm just not advanced enough to figure it out.

Right now, I have a login/register modal that pops up when someone selects the Login/Register link. It works as intended, no issues there.

```
<li class='nav__item'><a data-modal='modal-all' class='md-trigger nav__link nav__link--btn btn--show-modal' href='#'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-sign-in'></i> Log In/Register</a></li>
```

But, what I would like to do is redirect to a separate login or register page when on a mobile device, or smaller screen. My modal is both a login and register one, which users can switch between depending on what they need. I don't like the way it is working when shrank down to a tiny screen, it makes it too hard to see, which is why I would rather just redirect to a simpler login page for mobile clients.

I have been looking at the following site, https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls, but not sure how this can help me, as I don't really want to redirect a whole site to a mobile version, just to one page, based on a submit button for logins.

Is there a simple solution, whether with css, javascript, etc? Just for clarification, I am using javascript, css, and ejs as a templating engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should improve your CSS in this case, but here's one way to redirect pages

```
window.onload = function() {
 window.location.href = "url-here";
}
```

Comment: I could definitely improve the css for the modal on smaller screens, but there are a whole host of other issues I need to work out with it that I rather not get into here. Nothing breaking, just not what I am looking for. But in this case how would I use this function to redirect when I press the submit button? Instead of the modal opening it would take me to the mobile login page, say when the viewport was below 40rem. I'm not sure how I would implement this.

Comment: I see. Please, remember to set the question as solved if the presented solution fixed your problem. Cheers!